# Drupal 8 - The website encountered an unexpected error.

Tags: drupal-8

I was adding modules and installing them yesterday and I get this error now: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." I can't login at all or access anything from the url. I tried deleting the modules but it still isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have access to the database, try looking at the `watchdog` table for clues. The SQL Query `SELECT * FROM watchdog ORDER BY wid DESC;` will return watchdog entries sorted by newest first.

Answer (score 1):

To expose what's up, add the following line to your settings.php

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

What's happening is that the code is failing fairly deep into the execution and it may not even be a syntax error. In my case, it was the MySQL user was not associated with the MySQL DB, so the connection was failing as what the application

Answer (score 0):

The models are probably still in database even though you deleted it from code ?
If you have access to drush, you can in-install it via drush. If not you need to change entries in the database tables